# Electric field due to non-concentric spherical cavity in a non-conducting charged sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

I am unable to grab the concept of electric field due to non-concentric shells . Like in case of concentric shells , for example if we consider a solid shell with outer radius 'R' and inner radius 'r' with volume charge density $\rho$ and centre as $O$then for field at $r \leq R $ at a point $A$ inside the hollow cavity the field will be zero . If we want to find the electric field at a point B where B lies $ r \le B \le R$ then the electric field will be

$$\vec{E}_B = \frac{K \frac43 \Pi (OB^3-r^3) \rho}{OB^3} \vec{OB}$$
Which further will be

$$\vec{E}_B= \frac{\rho(OB^3-r^3)}{3 \epsilon_0 OB^3}\vec{OB}$$

Here $K$ is $$ \frac{1}{4 \Pi \epsilon_0}$$

This is using the fact that electric field inside and outside the shell is in radial direction .

Now I want to calculate Electric field for a same sphere where the shell is non concentric and point B lies where the point B is on the shell ( not in the spherical cavity ).My textbook says that you consider the inside shell to have negative charge density $-\rho$ and outside sphere to have $+\rho$ and then calculate the field at B due to both of them . But I want to calculate the way mentioned for concentric shell .