# Potential between a metal sphere and spherical shell which are not quite concentric

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, potential, spherical-harmonics

I have been struggling with this problem for some time by now.

> An insulated metal sphere of radius $a$ with total charge $q$ is placed inside a hollow grounded metal sphere of radius $b$. The centre of the inner sphere is slightly displaced from the centre of the outer sphere so that the distance between the two centres is $\delta$ , with $\delta <<a, b$.
>
> Find the charge distribution of the inner sphere and the force acting on it for $\delta >0$.

I have shown that $r = b+\delta cos\theta$, where $r$ is the distance between the centre of the sphere and a point on the spherical shell. But I don't know how to impose the boundary conditions in the solution of the Laplace equation.

Comment: Related but not answered: [Electric field due to non-concentric spherical cavity in a non-conducting charged sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489633)